# While loop not working for every index

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php, but I had used while loop and it worked. But in this case i don't know why it is not working.

I am using following query to fetch data from mysql data base.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `groupMembers` WHERE group_id = '$group_id'";
if ($result = mysql_query($query)) {
    # code...
    echo mysql_num_rows($result);
}
```

It prints 2 as number of rows.
 **But the problem is in following while loop:-**

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    # code...
    echo $data['member_id'];
}
```

I prints only one member's id. *(the second one == member_2)*

The above query returns 2 rows when run in mysql :-

```
member_id | group_id
----------|----------
member_1  | group_1
member_2  | group_1
```

Comment: Show more code - what happens before `while`.

Comment: And stop using `mysql_` functions. In php7 they are __removed__.

Comment: `mysql` has been deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql`.

Comment: Use mysqli or PDO functions with prepared statements. mysql functions are depreciated and vunerable to SQL injection

Comment: $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);

check your data first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i had same problem,i was calling following code two times

```
mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

Show more code - what happens before while

Comment: Thanks. You are right, i am calling this {$sel = mysql_fetch_array($result) } before while. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

first try mysql_num_rows in how many rows is returns. 
if "0" then can't fetch any record from your mysql and check your sql query. if return no of row then try below code:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Enjoy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

That is because when it create array for your MySQL query it will change me with to same value "group_1" 
Try to convert mysqli_fetch_array to mysqli_fetch_assoc instead

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `groupMembers` WHERE group_id = '$group_id'";
```

Here,$group_id can't be place between '';

Answer (score 0):

use `$results->fetch_assoc();` which get your data

```
<?php

// your database connection 

if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo 'Member Id:' . $row["member_id"] . '<br>';

    }
} else {
    echo " No Result";
}
?>
```